# Space Multiple Images Horizontally (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to space 5 small images horizontally in flutter, but I can't seem to find a simple answer. Maybe I'm just stressed that I can't learn by asking questions... Here's what I have:

```
body: Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
          ),
          ),
        ],
        ),
))));
```

Where would I place the next button code? Thank you for understanding!

Comment: I think you can find the answer in [Row class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [Column class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
Row(
  children: <Widget> [
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
　　    ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
　　    ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
　　    ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
　　    ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('assets/button1.png'),
　　    ),
    ),
  ]
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank YOU!!! ...so much code for such a seemingly simple thing. But thank you! :)

Comment: You can also use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` on your row to automatically get some space around the natural-sized buttons.  Also, Flatbutton says: "This class is obsolete, please use TextButton instead.".

Answer (score 1):

```
Row(
  children: <Widget> [
    Expanded(
      child: FImage.asset('assets/image1.png'),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Image.asset('assets/image2.png'),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Image.asset('assets/image3.png'),

    Expanded(
      child: Image.asset('assets/image4.png'),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Image.asset('assets/image5.png'),
    ),
  ]
```

That is one way to render 5 images horizontally. I don't know why you had these `FlatButton()` widgets there.

But remember that `Row()` widget in general puts widgets **horizontally** *in a row*.

There is also the `Column()` widget whereas it puts its' children widgets **vertically**, like being *in a column*.